# How to get property of parent View in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

This is probably beyond easy,  but I'm having a hard time to figure out how to access properties of parent views:

```
App.ParentView = Ember.View.extend({
  foo: 'bar',

  child_view: Ember.View.extend({

    init: function(){
       // get the value of App.ParentView.foo
       //  ???
    }
  })

});
```

Comment: Please note that in many cases accessing the parent view is a sign of code smell. However, it's hard to say more without knowing details here.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To get the view: `this.get('parentView')`

To get the value of foo `this.get('parentView.foo')`

Comment: Given a situation where you want to access the parent view in handlebars, you can use `{{view.parentView.foo}}`. ie: `{{#view Wrapper}}<div>{{view.parentView.foo}}</div>{{/view}}`

Comment: Newbies heads up! The code above here says App.parentView wich is misleading. You should always get("parentView") regardless to the name you have given your view.

Answer (score 4):

In Ember before 1.0.pre you could also use `getPath` method, instead of chains of get(), for more succinct (and generally safer) code:

```
this.getPath("parentView.foo");
```

What's cool in Ember 1.0.pre is that `get()` method now supports paths, so you can write

```
this.get("parentView.foo");
```

Answer (score 3):

Tom is correct. I also created a JS Fiddle to demonstrate this and also illustrate the special `contentView` property, which can be useful in this type of situation: http://jsfiddle.net/rSLQK/2/