# Any method for accessing parent object properties in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9279696/359104) shows how to get properties of parent views.

Is there a way to achieve the same with general `Ember.Object`s. For example how does the `child` access properties of `App.Parent`:

```
App.Parent = Ember.Object.extend({
  parentProperty: 'someValue',

  child: App.Child.create()  

});

App.Child = Ember.Object.extend({
   init: function(){
     // I don't know which is my parent object
     // but I still want to access the value of `parentProperty`
     // var parentProperty = ???

   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together a jsfiddle demonstrating how to update a child object with a "parent" property. The basic idea is check for the presence of a child on creation of the parent, and watch in case the child changes.

http://jsfiddle.net/KqCXr/6/

Hopefully, it will help. Comment here is you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Can you pass the parent in when you create the child?

```
App.Parent = Ember.Object.extend({
  parentProperty: 'someValue',

  child: App.Child.create({ parent: App.Parent })  
})
```

Comment: Can't always do this, especially if the parent is an instance in an array.