# How to access parent properties from a child view created using `createElement`

Tags: ember.js

I have created a view which supports drag and drop following the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762484/ember-js-html5-drag-and-drop-shopping-cart-demo). Now I am trying to set the drag image for each view based on its own content. Here is coffeescript for part of the code that I have issue with:

```
App.BlockView = Ember.View.extend(App.Draggable, {
  classNames: ['block'],
  mouseDown: ->
    console.log "clicked on #{@get 'elementId'} block and thumbnail is #{@get 'block.thumbnail'}" #this works
  ,
  dragIconElement: Em.View.create({
    attributeBindings: ['src'],
    tagName: 'img',
    #src: @get 'block.thumbnail', #this does not work
    src: @get 'parentView.block.thumbnail', #this does not work either
  }).createElement().get('element')
  ...
})
```

As you can see I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279696/how-to-get-property-of-parent-view-in-ember), but it did not work. Here is the errors I get in both cases above:

```
TypeError: this.get is not a function
src: this.get('parentView.block.thumbnail')
```

I am using Ember 1.0pre1 I don’t know how to access parent level scope here, and there is probably something basic I am missing here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: when u say @get('block.thumbnail') is that a property of App.Draggable mixin?

Comment: @Unspecified no it is a property of the parent view. As you can see I can directly access it from the mouseDown function.

Comment: by parent view I mean `App.BlockView`

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of `createElement` at `src: @get 'parentView.block.thumbnail'`, here `this` doesnt point to the current view(I guess it refers to window object, depends on ur code), better use it as a computed property

```
src: (->
  @get 'parentView.block.thumbnail'
).property()
```